# Using reCAPTCHA and enctype="multipart/form-data" together

Tags: php, recaptcha, enctype

I have a file upload form on which I also want to use the Google reCAPTCHA.

If I have the following

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="file" name="filename">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="***"></div>
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

the I can use the reCAPTCHA, but cannot upload the file.

However, if I use:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="filename">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="***"></div>
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I can upload the file successfully, <s>and use the reCAPTCHA **provided that the file is a text file.** I cannot get it to work if I try to upload a pdf file.</s>

When uploading a text file, the $_POST contains the 'g-recaptcha-response', but when uploading a pdf, the $_POST does not contain the 'g-recaptcha-response'.

Can someone explain what is going wrong here?

**EDIT**
It seems like it's actually a filesize problem.
Files larger than ~200kb cannot be sent whatever their format.

I have upload_max_filesize = 2M in my php.ini file, so I'm not sure why 200kb is too large...

Any thoughts?

**EDIT 2: More information**

It looks like the $_FILE contains the error code 3: UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL.

I don't see why the file cannot be uploaded completely.

**EDIT 3: Getting somewhere**

<s>I can now upload files. It seems like I need to put the reCAPTCHA **before** the file input.</s>

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="***"></div>
    <input type="file" name="filename">
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Can anyone elaborate on why this might be the case?

**Edit 4: Spoke too soon**

Switching the order makes the g-recaptcha-response' appear in $_POST, but I am still getting the error code 3: UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL.

**Edit 5**

It looks like the file is being uploaded correctly, since I can see it in the header parameters (firefox debugger). It seems like php is just not filling in the $_FILE array properly...

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same code on a different server and it worked fine.

Looks like the problem was that the server I set up has some sort of configuration issue. **It actually has nothing to do with the interaction of reCAPTCHA and the file input + enctype.**

I will update if I figure out what the configuration problem is.

Answer (score -1):

Create a hidden variable in some name. On submit copy ReCaptcha response (document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').value) to that variable and on server side verification use the variable instead of 'g-recaptcha-response'.